# cgi.FieldStorage not reads json data from requests.post

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, python-requests, wsgi

I've setup simple server as described in Python Cookbook (ch.11)

```
# server.py

import cgi


def notfound_404(environ, start_response):
    start_response('404 Not found', [('Content-type', 'text-plain')])
    return [b'Not found']


class PathDispatcher:
    def __init__(self):
        self.pathmap = {}

    def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
        path = environ['PATH_INFO']

        post_env = environ.copy()
        post_env['QUERY_STRING'] = ''

        params = cgi.FieldStorage(fp=environ['wsgi.input'], environ=post_env, keep_blank_values=True)

        environ['params'] = {key: params.getvalue(key) for key in params}

        method = environ['REQUEST_METHOD'].lower()

        handler = self.pathmap.get((method, path), notfound_404)
        return handler(environ, start_response)

    def register(self, method, path, function):
        self.pathmap[method.lower(), path] = function
        return function
```

and

```
# app.py

def send_json(environ, start_response):
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-type', 'text/plain')])

    params = environ['params']

    result = ""

    for key, param in params.iteritems():
        result += str(key) + ' :: ' + str(param) + '\n'

    yield result.encode('utf-8')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    from server import PathDispatcher
    from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server

    dispatcher = PathDispatcher()
    dispatcher.register('POST', '/send-json', send_json)

    httpd = make_server('', 8080, dispatcher)
    print('Listening on 8080...')

    httpd.handle_request()
```

Simple agent sends some json data with python.requests

```
# agent.py

import requests
import json

json_data = {'some': 'data', 'moredata':[{1: 'one'}, {2: 'two'}]}

url = "http://localhost:8080/send-json"
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

r = requests.post(url=url, data=json.dumps(json_data), headers=headers)

print r.text
```

Unfortunately, it produces errors like this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 85, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "/home/phux/PycharmProjects/printoscope_sql_injection/server.py", line 24, in __call__
    environ['params'] = {key: params.getvalue(key) for key in params}
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/cgi.py", line 517, in __iter__
    return iter(self.keys())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/cgi.py", line 582, in keys
    raise TypeError, "not indexable"
TypeError: not indexable
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Sep/2015 12:25:17] "POST /initial-scan HTTP/1.1" 500 59
```

Application cannot iterate over the received data and wsgi.FieldStorage doesn't contain MiniFieldStorage fields just raw json data

```
FieldStorage(None, None, '{"moredata": [{"1": "one"}, {"2": "two"}], "some": "data"}')
```

If I try to send data like this

```
r = requests.post(url=url, data=json_data)
```

everything works fine and FieldStorage looks fine

```
FieldStorage(None, None, [MiniFieldStorage('moredata', '1'), MiniFieldStorage('moredata', '2'), MiniFieldStorage('some', 'data')])
```

BUT I need to receive json data in the final application, so ...

Thanks in advance

Phux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## --------------SOLUTION-------------

Just replace these lines in server.py

```
post_env = environ.copy()
post_env['QUERY_STRING'] = ''

params = cgi.FieldStorage(fp=environ['wsgi.input'], environ=post_env, keep_blank_values=True)

environ['params'] = {key: params.getvalue(key) for key in params}
```

With this

```
try:
    request_body_size = int(environ.get('CONTENT_LENGTH', 0))
except ValueError:
    request_body_size = 0

request_body = environ['wsgi.input'].read(request_body_size)

params = json.loads(request_body)

environ['params'] = {key: params[key] for key in params}
```

cgi.FieldStorage expects form and I don't send one ... and this is the root of the problem. Some slight modification in app.py is also needed, but this is not the case and can be easily adjusted.